# Coldfusion 10, IIS 7.5 - Getting a 404 even though file exists

Tags: iis, coldfusion, http-status-code-404

I'm getting a 404 even though the page exists on disk.

I've ran the Web Server Configuration Tool and rebooted several times.

Handler mapping for .cfm files (configuration tool seems to have worked):
C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.dll

Virtual Paths:
root/index.cfm <- works
root/dan.cfm <- doesn't work

Server:
Windows 2008 R2, IIS 7.5 and Coldfusion 10

Rest of my configuration:
[image: desktop screenshot]

**Update 1**

NTFS Security Information on /wsconfig/1 folder:
[image]

**Answer - TLDR**

Map a virtual directory named "jakarta" to CFUSION INSTALL\config\wsconfig{instance id}

No need to add APPPool permissions to folder...

Comment: Does the configured application pool account have change access to the  `C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1` directory?

Comment: is your system clock correct? is cfadmin > server settings > cache > Cache web server paths > checked or unchecked (uncheck it)?  while you're there, try clearing template caches.

Comment: @travis it was unchecked, sys time is good, cleared template caches... still no go.

Comment: @Tomalak I added the pool to the folder... still doesn't work.

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus This looks promising, too: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4910342, so does this: http://www.jasonholden.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/8/26/IIS-7-and-Coldfusion-10

Comment: @Tomalak yup, that was it... eventually found this, http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion10-iis-manual-connector-configuration.html, step 7... Add a reply, I'll mark it as an answer...

Comment: It's easier when you write up the answer yourself. You have all the details and paths and can write a quick description where to click and so on. I'm going to vote that up.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Right click on the website and add a mapped virtual directory named "jakarta" to C:\Coldfusion10\config\wsconfig{instance id} (in my case, it was \1 )

Comment: this seems like more of a patch then a solution, if you have more then one site, or new sites all the time, this is something that would have to be repeated. Is there not a way to avoid this step? and is there any information on why this virtual directory is required? what is the meaning?

Comment: You can use ColdFusion 10 > Web Server Configuration Tool to go create a new WSConfig{instance id} folder for a specific site. But if just want to use one config for all, then you'll need to manually add Jakata Folder. For more info, check this out [link] (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18a15-7ffb.html)