# IIS Sites will not show coldfusion pages from remote server

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I have two servers with sites set up in IIS. I have a third server with my web files on it. The two servers will serve the web files hosted the third server. The problem is they won't serve coldfusion files from the third severs. HTML files work fine but .cfm files throw a 404 file not found error. The debugging information simply gives a File not found. I'm authenticating correctly to the third server and the .cfm file is definitely there. If I move the web files locally to the two servers and point back locally everything works the way it should. I took a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993010/coldfusion-10-iis-7-5-getting-a-404-even-though-file-exists) but my virtual directories had already been mapped correctly. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better suited for Server Fault

Comment: It is coldfusion related on the server though. On topic in my eyes.

Comment: Scott is right, your question is not related to ColdFusion code it is related to IIS/ColdFusion server configuration. It is better suited for Server Fault. Regardless, you will need to provide a lot more detail in order to get much help. I wouldn't even know where to start with your question as currently written.